# how to create a jar using cmd adding gson

Tags: java, jar, gson

unable to include Gson jar dependency with the java class , so that i can create .jar

```
DecisionType.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerializedName
location: class com.abc.cdf.bean.DecisionType
    @SerializedName("checkout")
     ^
DecisionType.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerializedName
location: class com.abs.fggs.bean.DecisionType
    @SerializedName("cancelled")
```

Comment: Can you please include more information on how are you attempting to generate the Jar? Are you doing everything manually or using for example Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you want to build a jar file manually with class path dependencies.
Based on the above assumption:

To compile the java files with the class path dependencies:

This will compile all the java files under the given directory and will use xx-2.3.1.jar as its CP dependency (add how much ever wanted by separating with ;). The compiled .class files will be under target directory.

```
javac -cp xx-2.3.1.jar;. -d target\ com\rr\xx\bean\*.java
```

After the compilation, we can create a jar file using the following command:

```
jar cvf xyz.jar -C target\ .
```

If any query, post a comment..!